# No incomming connection from XDebug on Ubuntu VirtualMachine to PhpStorm on Windows host

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I have a Win7 on my laptop and a VMware Machine running Ubuntu.

On the last one I have my LAMP configured and also a samba server in order to be able to share my projects to Win7 (mapping a drive).

I just installed xdebug through a package manager and done the following configuration in the php.ini:

```
extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.199.2 # this is my $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
xdebug.remote_port=9055
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
```

Then I got through the following checklist:

- confirm xdebug is installed using phpinfo()
- got some marklets from [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) so I can easily send xdebug cookie
- in PHPStorm->Settings->PHP->Debug I have set the 9055 port for xdebug
- pressed the "phone icon" in PHPStorm in order to listen for incoming xdebug connection, and set debug key (same as the one sent by markets - 'xdebug')
- moved to browser, accessed my script url, start a debug session using marklet (confirmed afterwords the presence of debug key in phpinfo())
- marked a break point in my script
- refreshed browser page

But nothing works for me.

Comment: **1)** If you have any entries in "Settings | PHP | Servers" -- either configure them properly (path mappings) or just delete them (IDE will help you to set it up when connection will be established) **2)** Are you able to connect from your VM to PhpStorm via `telnet` (on xdebug port; "Phone handle" icon must be activated)? If not -- possibly using wrong IP or firewall on your Windows machine.

Comment: My first shot as well would be firewalls.

Comment: **P.S.** In case of troubles of this kind -- do not afraid to use **[xdebug.remote_log](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log)** -- at very least it will tell if xdebug receives debugging request and where it attempting to connect (IP:port). **P.P.S.** Do not forget to restart Apache after making changes to php.ini (depends, but required in most configurations)

Comment: I just tested with "telnet REMOTE_ADDR PORT" and connection was refused. Firewall settings seem to allow communications to/from PHPStorm. Yes, logging is a must - I shall do that right now - thank you for the hint!

Comment: Also double check that PhpStorm listens on your custom xdebug port (on Windows machine) and that it is actually PhpStorm (and not another IDE/program). Use `tcpview` (GUI; download from microsoft) or standard `netstat`)

Comment: It looks like the problem is this: When from Win7 I access a script from server on Ubuntu VM, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is 192.168... When I ping this from Ubuntu it replies, but when I telnet it using port from xdebug settings it doesn't accept. What works is telnet-ing to IP got from ISP. What goes wrong is that xdebug.remote_host is overwritten by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] so it connects to the wrong IP. I am not a network expert, but I hope this draws a picture.

Comment: I read again xdebug docs and found that xdebug.remote_connect_back is responsable for ignoring xdebug.remote_host. Now It seems that connection is tried to be established but I get this in PHPStorm "Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'".

Comment: Get rid of `extension=xdebug.so`. Xdebug HAS TO BE loaded via `zend_extension=`  1) http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide 2) http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: YES! That was the problem now. Please feel free to formulate a response that summaries all this so I can accept it. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm leaving this for you to do -- you describe your experience and what you did to resolve it (will be useful for other people who may face similar situation). At the end of the day it had nothing to do with PhpStorm -- only incorrect xdebug configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, the fix for my problem was this:

- enable `xdebug.remote_log` (where I could check for connection attempts and identify the exact IP to which xdebug was trying to connect) - [this was the key]
- removed/set to 0 `xdebug.remote_connect_back` (because it overwrites remote_host with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
- set the proper `xdebug.remote_host`
- removed `extension=xdebug.so` an loaded xdebug using only zend_extension

So, every time, do not forget to check the logs if exists! :)

Thanks to LazyOne for very helpful hints!